# JSON payload for push notification in iOS using parse

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, push-notification

com for push notification in my ios application, my code is working if i push using parse website in message box.
this is  some part of my code

```
 - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*) userInfo {

[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
// Create our Installation query
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];
 }
```

but i want to use json payload for this but i dont know how to make it and where to store json payload, so can any body tell me about json payload for push notification inios for ios6, 7  and ios 8 ?

Comment: What code works and what code fails? Do you get an error message or are you looking for an API to use?

Comment: no its working but i want to know about json payload, how can i use and where the put it

Comment: Why not edit the question to show your best attempt at putting the json to the code and listing compilation errors or what happens with your attempt at the code? It's hard to guess where and how you're putting it from your comment.